# Kivy: Listview - position of selected item

Tags: listview, kivy

I am stuck at one point in Kivy. As I understood, Kivy resembles Android style for UI(adapters, kv language). I went by the same logic.

I have list of items which are fed to ListAdapter. Now I need a method like in Android(onItemClick) which will give position of selected item. I didn't find anywhere, I read all docs but no clue about this. Yes, I can manually find some item through for-loop but it is unwanted for me.

Did anyone have answer for this?

With regards

Answer (score 0):

You can use ListAdapter and feed it with custom button widget. The custom widget can have a `on_press` function defined in it to return the `pos` of the widget.

main.py

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.listview import ListItemButton
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty


class MyBoxLayout(BoxLayout):
    button_list_obj = ObjectProperty()

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        mylist = ['First Button', 'Second Button', 'Third Button', 'Fourth Button', 'Fifth Button']
        self.button_list_obj.item_strings = mylist
        self.button_list_obj.adapter.data.clear()
        self.button_list_obj.adapter.data.extend(mylist)


class MyButton(ListItemButton):
    def print_pos(self, mybutton):
        print(self.pos)


class ButtonListTestApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return MyBoxLayout()

if __name__== "__main__":
    ButtonListTestApp().run()
```

buttonlisttest.kv

```
#: import main main
#: import ListAdapter kivy.adapters.listadapter.ListAdapter

<MyBoxLayout>:
    button_list_obj: button_list
    orientation: 'vertical'
    ListView:
        id: button_list
        adapter:
            ListAdapter(data=[], cls=main.MyButton)

<MyButton>
    on_press: root.print_pos(self)
```